MS Project Online (CSOM) read custom field value
I want to retrieve custom field value of the project with using CSOM.
I have a simple function to read project name and its custom fields.
When calling context.Load(project, x=> x[customField.InternalName]); it throws exception
The query expression 'x.get_Item(value(ProjectOnline_PWA.Form1+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).customField.InternalName)' is not supported.
private void ReadProjects(ProjectContext context)
{
    context.Load(context.Projects);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    PrintInfoText("==============Projects===============");
    foreach (PublishedProject project in context.Projects)
    {
        PrintInfoText("ID:" + project.Id);
        PrintInfoText("Name:" + project.Name);

        PrintInfoText("CustomFields:");
        context.Load(project.CustomFields);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var customField in project.CustomFields)
        {
            PrintInfoText("    customField_ID:" + customField.Id);
            PrintInfoText("    customField_Name:" + customField.Name);
            PrintInfoText("    customField_InternalName:" + customField.InternalName);
            context.Load(project, x=> x[customField.InternalName]);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            PrintInfoText("    customField_Value:" + project[customField.InternalName]);
        }

        PrintInfoText("====================================");
    }
    PrintInfoText("==============End_Projects=============");
}

Can anyone advise how I can extract the value of custom field?
